# how to only indent brackets after case labels using clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I wanna a style that only indent brackets after case labels, while keeping case label not indented.

this is what I want:

```cpp
switch(a)
{
case 1:
    {
        do_some_thing();
    }
    break;
}
```

I find an option `IndentCaseLabels`, but it will the whole things include the case label, neither true or false isn't what I want

```cpp
true:
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
    {
        do_some_thing();
    }
    break;
}

false:
switch(a)
{
case 1:
{
    do_some_thing();
}
break;
}
```

Is this style **possible** in clang-format? If is, how could I Configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just immediate above one you found in the manual.

```
IndentCaseBlocks: true
```

> Indent case label blocks one level from the case label.

```
false:                                 true:
switch (fool) {                vs.     switch (fool) {
case 1: {                              case 1:
  bar();                                 {
} break;                                   bar();
default: {                               }
  plop();                                break;
}                                      default:
}                                        {
                                           plop();
                                         }
```

Comment: omg I just miss it. thx a lot